# How to load the values from Excel to a table using PHP

Tags: php, excel, import

Is there any way to load the values from MS Excel to a database table using PHP?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please consider including additional information.  What have you tried so far?  Which problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to load XLS directly from PHP it's possible .
 [`http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

Comment: i tried that..
my requirement is to display the row one by one on each day,as thought for the day,I have not that much knowledge in php..

Comment: So then you know what tool to use.. you cannot expect people to write all your code for you, if you don't know enough about php.. perhaps pick up some tutorials and ask specific questions..

Answer (score 0):

You could also save excel files in .csv format and take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

The example I provided opens the file and echos the content of the file.

[Live example](http://scriptit.kotisivut.name/test/)

The contents of the live example:

```
5   7   12
6   8   14
7   9   16
8   48  56
9   8   17
10  4   14
```

Third line is `=A1+B1`, `=A2+B2` and so on...

Comment: The pro in this approach is that it doesn't need any extra script attached.